# Matching unordered substrings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will remove/replace a problem string from my target string. In this case, my problem string is:

```
top:
```

My target string is:

```
F12+ vAWGPHGM
```

The challenge is the problem string is not always whole/intact and can come as individual characters.  For example:

```
F 1t2op+:vAWGPHGM
F t12o+p: vAWGPHGM
F1t2op+:vAWGPHGM
F 12top+: vAWGPHGM
```

I'm using pcre (php) regex.

Other considerations include the number above can be one or two digits and plus is not always present.  I've been trying to figure this out on regex101, but with not much luck. [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/RgqBQq/1)

Comment: For the string given you could just search for `[top:]+` and replace all matches with an empty string

Comment: the desired output is the target string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 captured groups to capture digits before and after `t` and use their back-references in replacement:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/\h*(\d*)t(\d*)o\+?p\+?:\h*/', '$1$2+ ', $str);
```

For all the 4 cases, replacement result will be:

```
F12+ vAWGPHGM
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/RgqBQq/3)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you just want to get rid off characters `t`, `o`, `p`, and `:`, if this is the case, then you can use a character class like this:

```
[top:]
```

**[Working demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/RgqBQq/2)**

Php code

```
$str = 'F 1t2op+:vHGM
F t12op: vHGM
1t2op+:vHGM
F 12top+: vHGM';

$result = preg_replace('/[top:]/', '', $str);
```

Keep in mind, that this doesn't follow any order, this just removes those chars from your string.